# android + KML + support for "+to:" tag

Tags: android, kml

I am facing a bit of problem with getting the route information from Google maps

I use the following url to get the complete route info. The query contains intermediate destination points
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=45.414569,-75.707324&daddr=45.430579,-75.686953+to:45.436207,-75.684726+to:45.434764,-75.683417+to:45.43415,-75.682838+to:45.429996,-75.683098&ie=UTF8&om=0&dirflg=w&output=kml

This gives me back a kml file but the kml file contains route coordinates only till the first destination point and no futher however if i remove the output parameter, the google map draws all the destinations mentioned in the "+to:" clause
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=45.414569,-75.707324&daddr=45.430579,-75.686953+to:45.436207,-75.684726+to:45.434764,-75.683417+to:45.43415,-75.682838+to:45.429996,-75.683098&ie=UTF8&om=0&dirflg=w

How to get all the route coordinates in KML including all the intermediate destination points

Thanks
surya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same question as [How to get KML of route with waypoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165741/google-maps-outputting-kml-file-of-route-with-waypoint/6300108#6300108)

Bottomline: multistep routing is only supported inside google maps and not through the downloaded kml.