# How to get KML of route with waypoints?

Tags: google-maps, kml, routes

I need to draw routes in my android app's MapView and to do so I'm using the coordinates listed in the KML output file of Google Maps.

The problem is: when I add a waypoint to a route, the KML file doesn't contain the complete route details and only shows the coordinates/directions from the source to the waypoint.

Here is [an example](http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&v=2.2&saddr=40.641963,-8.652592&mrsp=0&daddr=40.211490,-8.429200&mrad=41.149318,-8.607273&ie=UTF8&0&om=0). As you can see, the route is drawn correctly and all the directions are shown, but [the KML output](http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&v=2.2&saddr=40.641963,-8.652592&mrsp=0&daddr=40.211490,-8.429200&mrad=41.149318,-8.607273&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml) only has the details from the source to waypoint.

A solution is making two requests, one for source->waypoint and other for waypoint->destination, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multistep routing is only supported in google maps directly. 
See 
http://groups.google.com/group/kml-support-advanced/browse_thread/thread/1d57c9f0bc879141
and
http://groups.google.com/group/kml-support-getting-started/msg/e3d15213ac4ae9ed

Comment: Looks like making two requests is the only solution for now. Thanks.